# How to detect wheter running on 3G or Wi-Fi on iPhone?

Tags: wifi, detect, 3g

Some lines of code? Any experience?

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Detect 3G or WiFi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938650/ios-detect-3g-or-wifi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since than I made a pretty simple block based Reachability wrapper that strips all the outdated C-like Reachability code, poured into a much more Cocoa form.

[image]

Usage like:

```
[EPPZReachability reachHost:hostNameOrIPaddress
               completition:^(EPPZReachability *reachability)
{
    if (reachability.reachableViaCellular) [self doSomeLightweightStuff];
}];
```

See [Reachability with blocks for everyday use](http://eppz.eu/blog/reachability-with-blocks/) at [eppz!blog](http://eppz.eu/blog/reachability-with-blocks/), or grab it directly from [eppz!reachability at GitHub](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-reachability).

It **also works with IP addresses**, which turned out to be a pretty rare Reachability wrapper feature.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Apple's [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) code to retrieve this information:

Example:

```
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
[reach startNotifier];

NetworkStatus stat = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];

if(stat & NotReachable) {
   //not reachable
}

if(stat & ReachableViaWiFi) {
   //reachable via wifi
}

if(stat & ReachableViaWWAN) {
   //reachable via wwan
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple's `Reachability` class will give you this information.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html