# iOS Detect 3G or WiFi

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, reachability, 3g

I am not sure if this is possible, but I have this scenario.

I have a website displayed in my UIWebView which has the link set in a UISegmentedController.
They website can detect if you are on wifi or on the 3g network.

Now the segmented controller points to 2 different pages:
1 - An iPhone friendly login screen
2 - The home page, once you are logged in.

Now here is the question:

Can I program my application to detect whether it is to WIFI or 3G (I know you can do this), but then based on the answer go to segment 1 or 2

Kind of like this:

```
if (iPhone device is on 3g) {
    Go to Segment 1;
} else {
    Go to Segment 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iphone SDK detect Wifi and Carrier network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625158/iphone-sdk-detect-wifi-and-carrier-network)

Answer (score 211, accepted):

Using the code that Apple has provided [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/index.html)

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable) 
{
    //No internet
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    //WiFi
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    //3G
}
```

Comment: Yes Cool it worked!!! Had to do some fixing up of the reachability files as they had errors for iOS5 in it - but I am so happy right now. Unfortunately I can only give you 1 up vote:-)

Comment: Shouldn't you call `[reachability stopNotifier]` after you have the status?

Comment: That depends on the scope in which you use this code. If this were just in a method, `reachability` would go out of scope and be dealloced at the end of the method and `stopNotifier` would be called implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I assume it was an old version of this code that used `ReachableViaWifiNetwork`

Comment: That works great, but do not forget include in project general systemConfiguration.framework, otherwise you will get Linker problem

Comment: Also available on CocoaPods: `pod 'Reachability'`

Comment: Some know how to tell which WAN is? 3G, 4G, LTE?

Comment: _"Important: This document is no longer being updated. For the latest information about Apple SDKs, visit the documentation website."_

Comment: Yep, that’s correct, this is a very old question/answer but the link isn’t dead, it just as old as the answer.

Comment: @JamesWebster do you know of a up to date doc on this?

Answer (score 32):

If you don't want to import Reachability library or deal with notifiers, you can use this simple synchronous method:

```
typedef enum {
    ConnectionTypeUnknown,
    ConnectionTypeNone,
    ConnectionType3G,
    ConnectionTypeWiFi
} ConnectionType;


+ (ConnectionType)connectionType
{
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(NULL, "8.8.8.8");
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
    BOOL success = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags);
    CFRelease(reachability);
    if (!success) {
        return ConnectionTypeUnknown;
    }
    BOOL isReachable = ((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable) != 0);
    BOOL needsConnection = ((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsConnectionRequired) != 0);
    BOOL isNetworkReachable = (isReachable && !needsConnection);

    if (!isNetworkReachable) {
        return ConnectionTypeNone;
    } else if ((flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsIsWWAN) != 0) {
        return ConnectionType3G;
    } else {
        return ConnectionTypeWiFi;
    }
}
```

Comment: To use this helpful code, you have to #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h> and link to SystemConfiguration.framework.

Answer (score 18):

Import Apple's [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/index.html) and try this,

```
#import "Reachability.h"
#import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h>

//Try this
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [reachability startNotifier];

    NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(status == NotReachable)
    {
       NSLog(@"none");
        //No internet
    }
    else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
    {
        NSLog(@"Wifi");
        //WiFi
    }
    else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN)
    {
        NSLog(@"WWAN");


    //connection type
    CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netinfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
    _carrier = [[netinfo subscriberCellularProvider] carrierName];

    if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS]) {
        NSLog(@"2G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge]) {
        NSLog(@"2G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA]) {
        NSLog(@"3G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA]) {
        NSLog(@"3G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA]) {
        NSLog(@"3G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x]) {
        NSLog(@"2G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0]) {
        NSLog(@"3G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA]) {
        NSLog(@"3G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB]) {
        NSLog(@"3G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD]) {
        NSLog(@"3G");
    } else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE]) {
        NSLog(@"4G");
    }

    }
```

References(Links may broke in future) :

- [iOS Detect 3G or WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7938778/3411787)
- [Detect carrier connection type (3G / EDGE / GPRS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049660/detect-carrier-connection-type-3g-edge-gprs)
- [What are the differences between 1G, 2G, 3G, 4G and 5G?](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-1G-2G-3G-4G-and-5G)
- [CDMA2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDMA2000)
- [wiki 2G](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2G)
- [What is the difference between CDMA and WCDMA network sim](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-CDMA-and-WCDMA-network-sim)
- [What is "EV-DO Rev. A"?](http://www.mobileburn.com/definition.jsp?term=1xEV-DO+Rev+A)

Comment: First add SystemConfiguration framework, open this link https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachabilit' and download the file and copy Reachability.h, .m to your project and import #import "Reachability.h", #import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h> and finally copy paste above code.....

Answer (score 13):

When using iOS 12 or newer, you can use `NWPathMonitor` instead of the pre-historic `Reachability`class :

```
import Network // Put this on top of your class

let monitor = NWPathMonitor()

monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { path in
    if path.status != .satisfied {
        // Not connected
    }
    else if path.usesInterfaceType(.cellular) {
        // Cellular 3/4/5g connection
    }
    else if path.usesInterfaceType(.wifi) {
        // Wi-fi connection
    }
    else if path.usesInterfaceType(.wiredEthernet) {
        // Ethernet connection
    }
}

monitor.start(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background))
```

Comment: Can we define what host to test for that, like we could with  `Reachability.reachabilityWithHostName` ?

Answer (score 8):

I made a pretty simple block based Reachability wrapper that strips all the outdated C-like Reachability code, poured into a much more Cocoa form.

Usage like:

```
[EPPZReachability reachHost:hostNameOrIPaddress
               completition:^(EPPZReachability *reachability)
{
    if (reachability.reachableViaCellular) [self doSomeLightweightStuff];
}];
```

See [Reachability with blocks for everyday use](http://eppz.eu/blog/reachability-with-blocks/) at [eppz!blog](http://eppz.eu/blog/reachability-with-blocks/), or grab it directly from [eppz!reachability at GitHub](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-reachability).

It **also works with IP addresses**, which turned out to be a pretty rare Reachability wrapper feature.

Comment: Ummm why the 'screenshot'?

Comment: I had it from the blog post, candy for eyes.

Answer (score 5):

For swift we can use:

```
func getNetworkType()->String {
    do{
        let reachability:Reachability = try Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection()
        do{
            try reachability.startNotifier()
            let status = reachability.currentReachabilityStatus
            if(status == .NotReachable){
                return ""
            }else if (status == .ReachableViaWiFi){
                return "Wifi"
            }else if (status == .ReachableViaWWAN){
                let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
                let carrierType = networkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology
                switch carrierType{
                case CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS?,CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge?,CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x?: return "2G"
                case CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA?,CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA?,CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA?,CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0?,CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA?,CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB?,CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD?: return "3G"
                case CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE?: return "4G"
                default: return ""
                }

                // Get carrier name

            }else{
                return ""
            }
        }catch{
            return ""
        }

    }catch{
        return ""
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Class method is as follow

```
+(NSString*)connectedNetworkType {
     Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
        [reachability startNotifier];

        NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

        if(status == NotReachable) {
            NSLog(@"none");
            //No internet
        }
        else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi) {
            NSLog(@"Wifi");
            //WiFi
            return @"Wifi";
        }
        else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN){
            NSLog(@"WWAN");
            //connection type
            CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netinfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
            //    _carrier = [[netinfo subscriberCellularProvider] carrierName];
            if (([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS])
                ||([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge])
                ||([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x])) {
                NSLog(@"2G");
                return @"2G";
            }
            else if (([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA])
                     ||([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA])
                     ||([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA])
                     ||([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0])
                     ||([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA])
                     ||([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB])
                     ||([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD])){
                NSLog(@"3G");
                return @"3G";
            }
            else if ([netinfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology isEqualToString:CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE]) {
                NSLog(@"4G");
                return @"4G";

            }
        }
        return @"-1";//default unknown
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#import <ifaddrs.h>
#import <arpa/inet.h>

BOOL CheckWiFi() {

    struct ifaddrs *interfaces = NULL;
    struct ifaddrs *temp_addr = NULL;

    BOOL hasWifi = NO;

    int err = getifaddrs(&interfaces);
    if(err == 0) {

        temp_addr = interfaces; 

        while(temp_addr) {

            if(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {

                struct sockaddr_in *addr = (struct sockaddr_in *)temp_addr->ifa_addr;

                if(memcmp(temp_addr->ifa_name, "en", 2) == 0) {
                    hasWifi = YES;
                    break;
                }
            }

            temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next;
        }
    }

    freeifaddrs(interfaces);
    return hasWifi;
}
```

To check if you are in a wifi, this saves the costly check of making a connection. Check for ifa_name "bridge" to check for internet sharing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xamarin or Monotouch you can use Reachability adapted class from Xamarin GitHub repository:

https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/ReachabilitySample/reachability.cs

So add it to your project and call `Reachability.InternetConnectionStatus()`

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Reachability or using Swift simple answer is here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63837522/6342609

Answer (score 1):

Swift version with 5G support; based on several answers.

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration
import CoreTelephony

/// Returns current network connection type(e.g. 4G, WIFI). It may take some time; so there is the suggestion not to use it on the main queue.
static func connectionType() -> ConnectionType {
    guard let reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, "www.google.com") else {
        return .noConnection
    }
    
    var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
    SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags)
    
    guard flags.contains(.reachable) else { return .noConnection }
    guard flags.contains(.isWWAN) else { return .wifi }
    
    let networkInfo = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()
    let carrierTypeName: String?
    
    if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {
        carrierTypeName = networkInfo.serviceCurrentRadioAccessTechnology?.first?.value
    } else {
        carrierTypeName = networkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology
    }
    
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
        switch carrierTypeName {
            case CTRadioAccessTechnologyNR, CTRadioAccessTechnologyNRNSA:
                return .cellular5G
            default:
                break
        }
    }
    
    switch carrierTypeName {
        case CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS, CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge, CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x:
            return .cellular2G
        case CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE:
            return .cellular4G
        case nil:
            return .unknown
        default:
            return .cellular3G
    }
}

enum ConnectionType: CustomStringConvertible {
    case noConnection, unknown, wifi, cellular2G, cellular3G, cellular4G, cellular5G
        
    var description: String {
        switch self {
            case .noConnection:
                return "no connection"
            case .unknown:
                return "unknown"
            case .wifi:
                return "WIFI"
            case .cellular2G:
                return "2G"
            case .cellular3G:
                return "3G"
            case .cellular4G:
                return "LTE"
            case .cellular5G:
                return "5G"
        }
    }
}
```