# How can i find programmatically iPhone device connected 3G network or Wifi in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, wifi, 3g-network

Hi i need to find out whether iPhone internet connected 3G or 2G or WIFI network 
any suggestions

Thanks

Sravan

Comment: why vote down my question plz clarify my doubt...?

Comment: plz provide any sample code or any link it will be helpful for me...

Comment: Please refer Ben Groot's answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049660/detect-carrier-connection-type-3g-edge-gprs. And its **Core Telephony** framework not CFNetworking

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Download Reachability Class for iOS from this link:-**     https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

1)**Add Reachability.h &.m in your Project**, make sure you **make it ARC compatible by adding flag -fno-objc-arc**

2)**Now, check the connection type in your view controller**

```
  Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    [reachability startNotifier];

    NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(status == NotReachable) 
    {
        //No internet
    }
    else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
    {
        //WiFi
    }
    else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
    {
        //3G
    }
```

Comment: thanks but i need to show alert when user login to my app ur connected via 3G or Wifi network and if internet connectivity not avalible then it's show alert please check ur network connection

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Reachability` library written by tonymillion](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability).
If you don't wan to use ARC, there is also the Apple Reachability library.

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look inside of < CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h >

You will see that there is a currentRadioAccessTechnology property exposed on CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *netInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Radio access technology:\n%@",
       netInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology);
```

You can subscribe to changes via:

```
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter
    addObserverForName:CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification
                object:nil
                 queue:nil
            usingBlock:^(NSNotification __unused *notification) {
                CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *current =
                    [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc] init];
                NSLog(@"Updated Radio access technology:\n%@",
                       current.currentRadioAccessTechnology);
            }];
```