# iOS Communicate with LTE Similar to BLE Interaction

Tags: ios, swift, lte

I have a device that can be communicated with over `LTE` with the same functionality as you normally get through `BLE`.

However, I'm having a hard time understanding how you communicate with, and get callbacks from an `LTE` device in the same way you do with BLE.

It doesn't seem that there is a library like `CoreLTE` but is there a standard way to use `LTE` like we use `BLE` (`CoreBLE`)?

In other words, how does one do essentially something line:

```
func lteCentralManager(lteCentral:LTECentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral ltePeripheral:LTEPeripheral, 
...
lteManager.connectPeripheral(ltePeripheral,  options:nil)
...
```

NOTE: I realize that the technologies are different.  The above is only meant to make the point of what I'm trying to do - not imply that the calls would be the same.

If there is no standard way to do this, does anyone know a good place to start figuring it out with iOS?  I've read the standards.  I'm just looking for how to use it now in iOS.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'd rephrase my title and the relevant parts of my question if I were you because library requests are off-topic, and that doesn't seem to be quite what you are asking for. Somebody who only read the title would probably vote to close as off-topic.

Comment: You are correct!  Typing before coffee. Thank you!

Comment: LTE, like Edge, 2G, 3G etc.? Is it about "LTE Direct" (only thing I found: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTE_(telecommunication)#LTE_Direct). If yes, it seems to be created by Qualcomm, so you may check there.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that same link. I'll update this as I find new info.

Comment: So it looks like there are no answers out there for this.  When we get to our LTE code I'll update here with what I find.

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not offer APIs to interact with the LTE modem directly, so this is impossible - not to mention, even if the hardware and software was capable of it, why would the <s>scammer</s>carrier allow you to talk to nearby devices directly instead of going through their network where they would charge you for that bandwidth?

If you need short-range communication between iOS and Mac devices you might want to take a look at [Multipeer Connectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity). Firechat uses it successfully to enable off-network chat between nearby devices.

Comment: Sorry.  Let me be "more" clear.  We would be acting through the carrier.  I simply don't know how one would receive the messages coming in "over the carrier" from a device that is connected, say, over Verizon.  How does one commission a device?  Connect to it?  Get data off it?  Does it adhere to certain protocols?  Does iOS expose that to normal developers?  I can't find any info on that at all.

Comment: @addzo iOS definitely doesn't expose any APIs for this at the moment. I don't think any carrier supports this at the moment, and I doubt they ever will - this requires quite a big upgrade to their infrastructure and wouldn't make them enough money (how would they even track how much bandwidth is being used given that it's a P2P protocol?). The reason you don't find anything yet is because at this stage this protocol is nothing more than a dream and a prototype somewhere in Qualcomm's lab - maybe (and that's a big maybe) in a few years we'll see wider adoption.

Comment: André Borie - Thanks for this! I was looking at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coretelephony/cttelephonynetworkinfo and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049660/detect-carrier-connection-type-3g-edge-gprs and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405566/mapping-ios-7-constants-to-2g-3g-4g-lte-etc?rq=1.
And they seem to imply you can do some communication.  I'll update as I get more info.