# CTTelephony to detect connection type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, reachability, core-telephony

I am trying to find out the connection type of a device.  I have implemented reachability but this only detects if the user is on wifi, offline, mobile data.. I am trying to find out how to detect in more detail e.g. 3g, 4g.

The below answer says CTTelephony but doesn't show how to implement it. My project doesn't like to #import  but the framework is linked up.

[Detect carrier connection type (3G / EDGE / GPRS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049660/detect-carrier-connection-type-3g-edge-gprs)

Anyone had this problem?

Comment: Did you add CoreTelephony to the project?

Comment: Yes, it's all linked in build phases etc, when try to import the framework into my header file i am prompted to with #import <CoreTelephony/> but the file is not found.

Comment: Which file are you using?

Comment: Manged to solve it.   I just pasted in #import <CoreTelephony/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo.h> and built the project and it worked