# iOS - Is there a way to get cellular frequency band(800/900/1800MHz)

Tags: ios, iphone, frequency, gsm, cellular-network

I have an app where I first check the network state using [Apple's Reachability sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Reachability_Reachability_m-DontLinkElementID_9) then I get the technology used, [like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20840971/3411293), using `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo`.
I didn't find anything about cellular band, is there a way to get this information?