# Is there a way to check the Internet connection quality in React Native (i.e. 3g vs LTE)?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I was looking at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html and appears that we do get a flag of either "cell" for iOS or "MOBILE" for Android, though is there any way to differentiate between Edge vs 3G vs LTE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you will have to go to the native side of things. Here you have examples for [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049660/detect-carrier-connection-type-3g-edge-gprs) and [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android). The binding to React Native is rather easy, and you can find some help on the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html).

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm surprised that there isn't already a module available for this but this doesn't seem terrible setting up.