# Don't show cellular data warning on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

If a user decides to not allow an app to access cellular data every time they try to open the app they are shown a warning telling them that cellular data is turned off. 
Is there a way in the SDK to stop showing this message or control when / where it is displayed?

Answer (score 1):

The system will show this message if you try to access the Internet when permission has been revoked. To prevent it from appearing, you could use Apple's [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) code to detect network availability, and only make web calls if the network is available.

See also, [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170888/is-there-a-cellular-data-usage-api-in-ios-7).