# Check Internet Availability for any Network in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift3, reachability

I am working on `iOS` `Swift 3` project i need to check internet connectivity for any network and display alert if internet is not available.Could Someone help me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @JonSnow i need to check for any network could u post ur answer

Comment: For more you can read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46482545/swift-how-to-check-if-my-app-has-wlan-permission-and-the-device-is-connected-to#46482656

Comment: You can use reachability library, to identify the network changes https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Comment: @Suresh could u post the answer

Comment: @anuj if you using Alamofire then check this short snippet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30743408/check-for-internet-connection-with-swift/46562290#46562290

Comment: @Jack i m not using Alamofire