# How to know by code if the user has disabled cellular data in Settings?

Tags: ios, settings, cellular-network

How to know by code if the user has disabled cellular data in Settings ?

I have tried with Reachability but this tell me only if internet connection is reachable...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot check this via code. Apple have not made this part of the public API. The best you can do is just check if there is connection as you're doing now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apple has yet to make any progress to be more open. But I think it will come !

Comment: As of iOS9, you can check to see if cellular data has been disabled for your app.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48160099/2941876