# iOS 10 Cellular Data Switch

Tags: ios, ios9, ios10, cellular-network

I'm trying to adapt my app to iOS 10 and I noticed that the cellular data switch was a bit different from iOS 9:

I'm wondering if there is a system level API or something in iOS 10 that allows me to know which cellular switch was toggled on for my app when I launch it.

Plus:I know I can check connectivity through Reachability but I want to manage the "Allow XXX to use data" alert. What could I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wozzi.png)

Comment: Same problem, no solution yet.

Comment: This capability is available for iOS9 or later using CTCellularData.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48160099/2941876