# How do I know if cellular access for my iOS application is disabled form Settings?

Tags: ios, networking, reachability

I am working on universal application in which I need to detect if cellular access for my application is disabled at any point of time from Settings app.
I have tried with Reachability class. However, could not achieve this with Reachability which we normally use to detect network availability.

Comment: look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954389/measuring-cellular-signal-strength  Might be useful

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48160099/2941876