# iOS: How to Set Connection Option on WiFi Only and WiFi with Mobile network,

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, reachability, nsconnection

- **Set connection type**

  - if selected wifi only when use only wifi, not use mobile network.
  - if selected Wifi with Mobile connection when use both connection as
    per as available.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170888/is-there-a-cellular-data-usage-api-in-ios-7[enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170888/is-there-a-cellular-data-usage-api-in-ios-7) Check above link

Comment: If it gives you solution then please upvote to my answer.