# Is is possible to make a specific http call using cellular while you are connected to wifi on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, wifi, cellular-network

I am developing an application for an operator. They want to get the msisdn of the user by making an http call using cellular connection. Can this also be done while you are connected to wifi. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Detect 3G or WiFi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938650/ios-detect-3g-or-wifi)

Comment: Do you ever know what is bind() socket call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as an developer you can not choose the connection used to make HTTP calls.

I've been developers an App for an operator for 3 years now and would also like this option, but Apple has not released any API for this.