# Build error in iOS (cross platform C++ library solution) while using reachability framework for detecting network interface type

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, reachability

I was trying use the code given here [Reachability sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7938778/2235397). But am facing some problems to do this. To use the code I have downloaded Reachability.h and Reachability.m from [here](https://github.com/eppz/eppz-reachability). But whenever I try to compile it fails to recognize *Reachability class*. The code block which causes the problem are given below -

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]; // in this line it doesn't recognize "Reachability"
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus]; // In this line it doesn't recognize "NetworkStatus"

if(status == NotReachable) 
{
    //No internet
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    //WiFi
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    //3G
}
```

Please note that I am using this code in iOS block in a cross platform C++ library solution. I need to resolve this issue as soon as possible. I am seeking for help to resolve the issue?

EDIT:

Build error is resolved after I have added condition check for **OBJC** macro. But it seems the code doesn't get compiled. Here is the edited code

```
#ifdef __OBJC__

Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable) 
{
    //No internet
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    //WiFi
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    //3G
}
#endif
```

I want to use the above code and also want to compile the code. How to do that?

Comment: So it's question about using Objective-C in C++ code?

Comment: So you haven't discovered Objective-C++ yet?

Comment: No. Would you please enlighten me on this? @trojanfoe

Comment: You need to call that code in Objective-C++ (`.mm` file).

Comment: That would be difficult, because adding .mm file in our project is prohibited. :(

Comment: You can add `.m` files but not `.mm` files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed. I have fixed the issue by using the core code of Reachability framework. If anyone faces the same issue I can help.

The issue was occurring because "NotReachable", "ReachableViaWifi" and "ReachableViaWWAN" are user defined enum. It is not included in "Rechability.h". So, I have downloaded a project on Reachability framework and find out the real system flag for these values. And solved the issue.