# Is there a way to pick the network bearer in iOS?

Tags: ios, networking

I know that on Android there is an API to specify which network bearer to use (WiFi vs cellular vs VPN).

Does iOS have an equivalent facility/API/capability?  I checked the documentation but it seems that it such API is not publicly available.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any way for an iOS app to *select* which type of network data is sent over. The sandbox keeps you from doing that.

If it's a problem like you're downloading a large file and don't want to do it over a user's cellular data connection (as a user, thank you!), you could use Apple's [`Reachability`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class to see what the current data connection is. [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7938778/1849664) shows how to do that:

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
[reachability startNotifier];

NetworkStatus status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if(status == NotReachable) 
{
    //No internet
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWiFi)
{
    //WiFi
}
else if (status == ReachableViaWWAN) 
{
    //3G
}
```