# How to let user open Wi-Fi when the Wi-Fi is not enable

Tags: ios, wifi

When user open my app, I want the Wi-Fi is enabled, it can have no connection ,but the Wi-Fi must be enabled. The query should return true when WiFi is enabled and device is not connected to any network.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no official support by Apple for this. There however is some trick to get the required result but there are changes of your app being rejected.

**Have a look at this unofficial trick:**
http://www.enigmaticape.com/blog/determine-wifi-enabled-ios-one-weird-trick

To answer your second question i.e. If wifi is enabled, you can find out if internet is accessible of not using this: [iOS Detect 3G or WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938650/ios-detect-3g-or-wifi)

Comment: Thanks, but I had tried the method in the link you posted, the log message is not like his, the enable wifi or disable wifi just log the same message, so I can not tell whether wifi is enabled. The second question we just also have to connect to internet ....