# Sending E-mail or SMS on the basis of Network Connection(Slow/Fast)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, connection

I want to implement a functionality of sending Email/SMS to a particular email address or number on the basis of data connection availability.
Three scenarios-

1) If data connection is a Wi-fi or 3G and above then send an email.

2) If data connection is 2G or lesser send a SMS.

3) If no data connection then do nothing.

So, how will I be able to get the connection type of an iPhone/iPad? I have searched on google and stackoverflow but didn't get the right answer. And will the solution be able to pass Apple's Review Cycle?

Thank you
Akshay

Comment: might help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589324/how-to-detect-wheter-running-on-3g-or-wi-fi-on-iphone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible to a certain extend, you will need to use Apples [`Reachability`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) code.

But you can only detect if you are on WiFi, WAN of not connection at all. Where WAN is either 3G or 2G.

Comment: Yes, 3g and 2g not possible to differentiate